# Encrypting BIND DNS Zone Transfers

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

Is there any BIND functionality to provide privacy (encryption) for zone transfers. TSIG and DNSSEC provide authentication. Maybe I am being paranoid!

Answer (score 5):

I think you're paranoid and see no reason to encrypt zonefiles. But if you really want to: set up a VPN between your master and slave nameservers and use that for transfering zonefiles.

Comment: Thanks i reckon you are right. The main concern is that the slave is located in china. BIND security has never been so important to me until now.

Comment: @user1036745 do be aware that any DNS queries hitting the slave that originate outside of PRC will be "inspected" by the Great Firewall of China.  If the queries match certain substrings they will send back fake answers too...